# What is SourceFunction#run is supposed to work in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I have implemented a Source by extending `RichSourceFunction` for our Message Queue that Flink doesn't support.

When I implements the run method whose signature is:

```
  override def run(sc: SourceFunction.SourceContext[String]): Unit = {

    val msg = read_from_mq
    sc.collect(msg)
  }
```

When the `run` method is called, if there is no newer message in message queue,

1. Should I run without calling `sc.collect` or
2. I can wait until newer data comes(in this case, `run` method will be blocked).

I would prefer the 2nd one,not sure if this is the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run method of a Flink source should loop, endlessly producing output until its cancel method is called. When there's nothing to produce, then it's best if you can find a way to do a blocking wait.

The [apache nifi source connector](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/NiFiSource.java) is another reasonable example to use as a model. You will note that it sleeps for a configurable interval when there's nothing for it to do.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know both options are functionally correct and will yield correct results.

This being said the second one is preferred because you're not holding the thread. In fact, if you take a look at the RabbitMQ connector implementation you'll notice that this exactly how it is implemented: inside its `run` it indirectly waits for messages to be placed on a `BlockingQueue`.